# Why I can't getting json in android?

Tags: php, android, json

I am having problem in getting one dimensional  `JSON` please guide me where either the problem is in my `JSON` or in my code?

JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "S000010",
        "name": "ZS Solutions",
        "email": "zswebs@gmail.com",
        "phone": "051-1234567",
        "address": "p.o.box 123",
        "about": "im the company\r\nHAhahhaa"
    }
}
```

Android activity `JSON` retrieval code:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("abc.php?Id="+id+"");

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse hresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = hresponse.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    String result=co(is);
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);

    JSONArray a=  json.getJSONArray(data);
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length(); i++) {

        json = a.getJSONObject(i);
        String  cname=json.getString("name");
        String  cemail=json.getString("email");
        String  cphone=json.getString("phone");
        String  caddress=json.getString("address");
        String  cabout=json.getString("about");
        Log.w("DATA  ","NAME  "+cname+"E-mail  "+cemail+"Phone "+cphone+"ADDRESS"+caddress+"ABOUT"+cabout);
    }


}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: It looks like data is an object not an array trying adding the [] around the object within data

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do and what's not working. If you have an exception or other runtime error, please add the logcat output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSONArray a=  json.getJSONArray(data);`  <-- this causing the Exception as

data is not a json Array, instead , it is a `JSONObject`

Your code should be

```
       JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);

       JSONObject jsonobj=json.getJSONObject("data");

        String  cname=jsonobj.getString("name");
        String  cemail=jsonobj.getString("email");
        String  cphone=jsonobj.getString("phone");
        String  caddress=jsonobj.getString("address");
        String  cabout=jsonobj.getString("about");
```

Comment: but name email phone address and about are in "data" how can i retrieve thesee ?

Comment: @Saad Please Check the above code, You can directly copy&paste the above

Comment: still not getting these valuse..:(

Comment: @Saad For the above mentioned JSONString it is the way to parse..log to check whether your json is returning vallue also check if there there any Exception, please post if any...

Comment: @Saad Ok...It seems there is problem while you are getting the json data, So try to identify it. If you not found post a question for that..this answers only your current question, i.e parsing json.

Comment: the problem was in my url(spelling mistake)..anyways thanks for your help..:)